# Facebook URL Debug: Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Does anyone know why "some" URLS get this error and others do not?

Error: Sorry, something went wrong.
We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.

I apologize for the lack of detail on this. I can't post a link as of yet but hoping someone has experienced this issue and found a resolution. Paging through the FB help pages directed me to here as well and it seems difficult to find the right place to report the problem directly to FB. I'm finding a lot of similar posts on StackOverflow with similar issues but no clear answers.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I hit this because Facebook changed the rules for what an acceptable ?state parameter.  I had % escape characters, and that appeared to no be illegal. I ended up moving my state to a query parameter on the redirect URL.

The specific rules are not actually documented: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Answer (score 1):

In my case I switched the product **Facebook Login for Business** to **Facebook Login**
and problem solved.

You can switch to Facebook Login by going to the **App Dashboard** > **Facebook Login for Business** > Settings and clicking the S**witch to Facebook Login** link.

Here is detail article

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/facebook-login-for-business/

Answer (score 0):

this is because the commenter OR user is blocked by facebook. in other words if a user is blocked by facebook for some features including COMMENTS, this error will be shown.

you can read full thread here http://www.codeloopers.com/social-media-f39/sorry-something-went-wrong-we-re-working-on-getting-this-fixed-as-soon-as-we-can-facebook-comment-box-error-on-wordpress-t321.html

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. Regardless, the link is busted, I tracked one down from archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20131206121602/http://www.codeloopers.com/social-media-f39/sorry-something-went-wrong-we-re-working-on-getting-this-fixed-as-soon-as-we-can-facebook-comment-box-error-on-wordpress-t321.html

Answer (score 0):

I am currently facing this issue, but in my case, in developer console everything is working, but request from my platform is failing and saying `"We're working on it and we'll get it fixed as soon as we can."` 
I've tried printing the URL and then calling that URL in browser and it is working as expected. I think Facebook have some mechanism for blocking specific requests.

Answer (score 0):

Just got this same error. In my case it was due to Facebook URL and parameters being deprecated. I was using a URL of the format:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=https%3A%2F%2Fspeaking.email
```

I changed this to this format:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fspeaking.email
```

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that the original post is somewhat dated. However, I managed to resolve the issue by navigating to https://business.facebook.com/latest/settings/profiles and proceeding to log out. This action effectively rectified the problem at hand.