# Can not log in facebook account

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, account-kit

I can not log in to my facebook account and I received that (attached file)([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnfu4.jpg)) 
I know that question was asked but **I have tried a lot of ways are: change DNS, delete cookies**,... but not working... and I don't think my account was hacked or blocked by Facebook. I can change my password with my email before. 
It happened when my brother log in his facebook account on my laptop and when I log in my account again, I received that error. After that, I know my account has logged on Microsoft Edge, I can connect with that but when I log out I can not log in again with that error I told

> (Sorry, something went wrong....)

Please help me :((

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. You may not be aware that this site is Q&A site for programming problems. If you were having problems with your _web page_ logging in to Facebook, it would fall under [tag:facebook-login] tag. Unfortunately, _you_ failing to log into Facebook is a user problem, and is off-topic for this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Why we has this topic (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495256/facebook-url-debug-sorry-something-went-wrong-were-working-on-getting-this-f) on stackoverflow?????????? Kidding?